# How to comment out code in a file VIA Terminal

Tags: command-line

I am following [This Tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/182261/how-to-change-virtual-screen-resolution-on-ubuntu-connecting-via-vnc-without-re/187274#187274) to make my Android an external monitor for my Ubuntu 12.04 computer.

How do I do the following:

> Edit your vnc session file
>
> `$ vi ~/.vnc/xstartup`
>
> Comment out everything and put this at the end
>
> `gnome-session &`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sed and echo are 2 commands in terminal . I am not using vi (editor) I prefer the simplest nano (editor) but now we will use sed (stream editor) and echo (line displayer) combined with tee (reader) trough a pipe | .

```
sed 's/^/#/g' -i ~/.vnc/xstartup

echo 'gnome-session &' | tee -a ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

If the file is admin protected (needs privileges) then

```
sudo sed 's/^/#/g' -i ~/.vnc/xstartup

echo 'gnome-session &' |sudo tee -a ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

Thanks